# What kind of tree is this (Seattle, WA)?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

This tree is a volunteer and I am hoping to find out what kind of tree it is.

Young tree

[image]

Leaf sample

[image]

Below is a more recent photo showing flowering.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information? Are there veins on the leaves? If so, how do they run? How big are the leaves (perspective with the camera is hard to tell how big the tree is in general)? Are there flowers? Anything budding? The more information, the better someone can identify the tree for you

Comment: The kind of leaf is typical of Fabaceae (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Laburnum. Probably a Common Laburnum *Laburnum anagyroides*, also known as a Golden Chain Tree. It is from central and southern Europe.

The seeds are poisonous.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laburnum_anagyroides

Here is a photo of the leaves
[image]
From http://www.saps.org.uk/trees/laburnum.htm

And the flower
[image]
http://wildflowerfinder.org.uk/Flowers/L/Laburnum/Laburnum.htm